# Build-in function for interpolating single pixels and small blobs

Tags: c++, image, opencv, interpolation, opencv3.1

**Problem**

Is there a build-in function for interpolating single pixels?
Given a normal image as `Mat` and a `Point`, e.g. an anomaly of the sensor or an outlier, is their some function to repair this `Point`?
Furthermore, if I have more than one `Point` connected (let's say a blob with area smaller 10x10) is there a possibility to fix them too?

**Trys but not really solutions**

It seems that interpolation is implemented in the geometric transformations including resizing images and to extrapolate pixels outside of the image with `borderInterpolate`, but I haven't found a possibility for single pixels or small clusters of pixels.

A solution with `medianBlur` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670692/how-to-detect-and-fix-dead-pixels-in-images-using-opencv) does not seem appropriate as it changes the whole image.

**Alternative**

If there isn't a build-in function, my idea would be to look at all 8-connected surrounding pixels which are not part of the blob and calculate the mean or weighted mean. If doing this iteratively, all missing or erroneous pixel should be filled. But this method would be dependent of the applied order to correct each pixel. Are there other suggestions?

**Update**

Here is an image to illustrate the problem. Left the original image with a contour marking the pixels to fix. Right side shows the fixed pixels. I hope to find some sophisticated algorithms to fix the pixel.

[image: Left: Original image with contour with pixels to fix. Right: pixels fixed]

Comment: See [despeckle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408979/remove-shapes-from-image-with-x-number-of-pixels-or-less)

Comment: One solution mentioned in the link could be helpful: The library Leptonica. Nevertheless, I would prefer a solution with pure opencv. The other suggested solutions there with ``morphologyEx`` seem to result in a binary image, if I'm right, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: you ask for hard algorithm. usually who that create projects like this not publish theme.

Comment: Some interpolation algorithms are well known and opencv provide a lot of algorithms. So I think there is the possibility, that some these algorithms are included and can be used in the desired way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-in function `inpaint` of OpenCV does the desired interpolation of chosen pixels. Simply create a mask with all pixels to be repaired.

See the documentation here: [OpenCV 3.2. Description: inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) and [Function: inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d0d/group__photo.html#gaedd30dfa0214fec4c88138b51d678085)